# Skype and Teamviewer do not run any more

Tags: skype, teamviewer

Have Ubuntu 14.04I was using SKYPE and Teamviewer up to the latest versions and then nothing, I can run every single application in my setup but those two.
I uninstalled  twice already click on their icons and nothing happens, all I remember seeing a dialog about an application requesting to wait  or force quit so I hit  wait and nothing happens. I've been using UBUNTU since version 6 I'm no newbie but this has stumped. I want to use these programs in my UBUNTU PC not in my other systems running MS Windows (have 7, 8, and 10 versions) What can I do to get my Skype and Teamviewer back to working order

Output from attempts to launch from terminal:

```
hp-m7640n@hpm7640n:~$ skype
skype: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so.4: undefined symbol: _ZNK14QWidgetPrivate17hasHeightForWidthEv)

hp-m7640n@hpm7640n:~$ teamviewer
Init... XRandRWait: No value set. Using default. XRandRWait: Started by user. Checking setup... Launching TeamViewer ... Launching TeamViewer GUI ...
```

Comment: What output do you see if you try to start respective application from a terminal window? Please edit your question, and copy-paste the terminal output.

Comment: these are the results as running from terminal skype:(hp-m7640n@hpm7640n:~$ skype 
skype: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so.4: undefined symbol: _ZNK14QWidgetPrivate17hasHeightForWidthEv)   teamviewer (hp-m7640n@hpm7640n:~$ teamviewer 

Init... 
XRandRWait: No value set. Using default. 
XRandRWait: Started by user. 
Checking setup... 
Launching TeamViewer ... 
Launching TeamViewer GUI ... )

Comment: Looks like I have to depend on windows to run these critical apps (SKYPE & TEAMVIEWER) I'm a small IT consultant and  depend on skype  and team viewer to avoid traveling to my clients sites,  with teamviewer  I can remotely update and service my client's systems. Thanks Gunnar  for your time. I can run  pretty much any other app from the CLI without any problem,  I do training shorts for my clients all winth my ubuntu system plus  I use it for graphic and web design  and music editing, Thanks again